# moment unix timestamp formats wrong date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert an Unix milliseconds timestamp to readable date.

My timestamp is 1525772511140.
The correct output should be something like:
29-05-2018 9:41:51AM

Now my code returns a wrong date: 31-10-50319 03:10...

code:

```
var timeStamp = new Date(1525772511140 * 1000);
var date = moment(timeStamp).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 1000?

Comment: But the timestamp is already milliseconds @lakshay

Comment: yeah I see that now

Comment: (*1000/1000) is redundant....no need to do that

Comment: @lakshay yea true lol

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use [`moment(Number)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/):

> Similar to `new Date(Number)`, you can create a moment by passing an integer value representing the number of *milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC)

```js
var date = moment(1525772511140).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
console.log(date);
// with seconds and AM/PM
date = moment(1525772511140).format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Native JavaScript solution (without moment.js) :

```js
var d = new Date(1525772511140);
console.log(
  ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' +
  ("0" + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + 
  d.getFullYear() + ' ' +
  d.getHours() + ':' +
  d.getMinutes()
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `*1000` from your statement and it works:

```js
var timeStamp = new Date(1525772511140);
var date = moment(timeStamp).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The timestamp is already in milliseconds so no need to multiply by 1000.

Comment: thanks but gives error 'invalid date'. in someway it works if i do Date(1525772511140 / 1000 * 1000)..

Comment: hmm thats weird when my output is diffrent

Comment: are you using the same `moment.js` import as I did? @pazta

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const date = moment(new Date(1525772511140)).toDate();
```

or

```
const date = moment(new Date(1525772511140)).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
moment.unix(1525772511140 / 1000).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answer is giving correct output.

In question expected output is **29-05-2018 9:41:51AM** which is `moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss A')`

Below is correct answer as per the question:

```js
let date = moment(1525772511140).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss A');
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

For more information about moment formats check this link: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: '...ssA' should be at the end of the format to match...not '...ss A'...that would put a space between the seconds and the AM/PM...which the example doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I was getting the unix timestamp in milliseconds. What worked for me was dividing the unix timestamp by 1000 and use with moment.unix() since moment.unix takes timestamp value in seconds:

```
let formattedDate = moment.unix(1646394914141 / 1000).format("yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
console.log(formattedDate); // 2022-03-04 03:13:56
```